# force all https requests to my front end proxy

Tags: node.js, redirect, nginx

I have a front end nginx reverse proxy and a backend nodejs app ... At the moment people can access the backend webpage via the proxy (which is great) but they can they totally bypass the front end proxy if they browse to the backend using the correct URL ... Has anyone been able to achieve this where they are somehow able to either stop the backend nodejs server from advertising or forcing all traffic that may go to it directly to the front end proxy ?

Comment: Firewall rules and not listing your back-end servers in public DNS. This is technically off-topic here as it's more of a question for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).